# Selecting numpy columns based on values in a row

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have a numpy array with 2 rows and 10 columns. I want to select columns with even values in the first row. The outcome I want can be obtained is as follows:

```
a = list(range(10))
b = list(reversed(range(10)))
c = np.concatenate([a, b]).reshape(2, 10).T
c[c[:, 0] % 2 == 0].T
```

However, this method transposes twice and I don't suppose it's very pythonic. Is there a way to do the same job cleaner?

Comment: Don't apologise for being new. We all were at some point. This is a well posed clear question, which is all you need to do to learn. Worst case, someone will mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy allows you to select along each dimension separately. You pass in a tuple of indices whose length is the number of dimensions.

Say your array is

```
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 10))
```

The even elements in the first row are given by the mask

```
m = (a[0, :] % 2 == 0)
```

You can use `a[0]` to get the first row instead of `a[0, :]` because missing indices are synonymous with the slice `:` (take everything).

Now you can apply the mask to just the *second* dimension:

```
result = a[:, m]
```

You can also convert the mask to indices first. There are subtle differences between the two approaches, which you won't see in this simple case. The biggest difference is usually that linear indices are a little faster, especially if applied more than once:

```
i = np.flatnonzero(m)
result = a[:, i]
```

Comment: Now, I get it. Thank you. The IndexError I got when I tried to pass `c[c[0]%2==0]` makes much more sense now.

Comment: Yup. `c[0] % 2 == 0` is a boolean array of size 10. The first dimension you are implicitly indexing has size 2. It doesn't match up